# Optimizing space complexity for a problem involving counting unique multiples of 2 or more numbers?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Sample input:

```
14
3
4
8
```

I just need to figure out the unique multiples of the last 3 numbers, up until the first number. So, the unique multiples of 3, 4, and 8 up until 14, which would be 3, 9, 12, 4, 8.

The solution I'm thinking of would either involve multiple data structures, and just appending to and counting the size of the structures at the end, or an O(N^2) solution that would involve iterating through the structure upon every potential insertion to avoid repeats.

Would a solution that reduces the complexity of this problem end up being more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: Is N the first number? You could modify a prime sieve to get an O(N log N)-time algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat note OP is optimizing for space complexity

Comment: Why 6 is not in the unique multiple list? Shouldn't the result be `3,6,9,12,4,8`?

Comment: Please clarify if you'd like all the multiples of the input numbers (for example, including the 6 that's not in your example output) or multiples constructed only from the input numbers themselves (which would seem aligned with your current example).

Comment: Please also clarify if you'd like to output the multiples in some order and if so what kind.

Comment: While [Matt Timmermans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738903/3789665) seems to have got it right (in contrast to [Dillon Davis answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54738717/3789665) accepted by you), your question would improve if you add the answer (there are *six* multiples not counting repetitions, *not* five) to the example (pointing out *this count is the answer*, and *not* the set of multiples) and repeated *space* in between `the complexity` in the concluding sentence. (*Counting* in problems more often refers to *tell the number* than to *generate qualified instances and count them*.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get by with `O(n)` space and `O(mlogn)` time complexity (`m` being number of total multiples) by using a min-heap. Populate the heap with your starting numbers, with their current multiple (which is just the number itself for now) as their key. Set a variable for `last_seen` to be smaller than your smallest starting number (maybe zero).

Now, delete the min key from the heap, if its greater than `last_seen` and less than or equal to your `target_value` print it. Then set `last_seen` equal to this key. Increase the value of the key (representing the current multiple) by the value of the starting number it stored (`3 + 3 -> 6`, `6 + 3 -> 9`, etc.) and re-add it to the min-heap. Repeat this process until the min key is greater than `target_value`. If at any point the min key equals `last_seen`, then that number is a duplicate- just skip the printing step and proceed as normal.

Comment: How might I keep track of the starting number each node stores?

Comment: @J.Doe Just store it as the value of each node in the min-heap.

Comment: But doesn't those values change as they're removed and added back on to the heap? Unless I'm misunderstanding something. As in, the initial heap is (3, left child = 4, right child = 8), you delete 3, add 3 to 3, then add 6 back on the heap, so the heap is now (4, left child = 6, right child = 8). Eventually, that 6 will be evaluated again, and you need to add 3 to 6, but where would that starting value of 3 be kept?

Comment: @J.Doe Each node in the heap has a key and a value. The key is what you order them by- the value is just additional information packed along side the key.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot all about that. Also, how did you arrive at the solution to use a min-heap? As in, what was your line of thinking in getting there?

Comment: @J.Doe I realized the "bottlenecks" in the problem were removing duplicates and finding the min, and the easiest way to do that is to order them. Sorting is expensive, and hashing wouldn't let me query for the min, so a min-heap it is.

Comment: Why would this problem involve finding the min?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188561/discussion-between-dillon-davis-and-j-doe).

Comment: @J.Doe I noticed you posted a follow up question. If either of these answers answer your question, feel free to accept one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate this quickly with only constant space.

Given **LIMIT, A, B, C**, the answer you want is the number of multiples of **A**, **B**, and **C**, minus the number of multiples of each pair (because they would have been counted twice), plus the number of multiples of all 3 (because it would have been counted 3 times and then subtracted 3 times).

Where **LCM(x,y,...)** is the lowest common multiple of its arguments, the formula is:

**floor(LIMIT/A) + floor(LIMIT/B) + floor(LIMIT/C) - floor(LIMIT/LCM(A,B)) - floor(LIMIT/LCM(A,C)) - floor(LIMIT/LCM(B,C)) + floor(LIMIT/LCM(A,B,C))**

For your example that's:

**floor(14/3) + floor(14/4) + floor(14/8) - floor(14/12) - floor(14/24) - floor(14/8) + floor(14/24)**

**= 4 + 3 + 1 - 1 - 0 - 1 + 0**

**= 6**

Hmm... you only have 5 numbers in your list for that example -- the number 6 is missing.

Comment: I think OP wants the numbers themselves, not the count. I could be wrong through- it wasn't explicitly stated what the output should be.

Comment: Also, what is the time complexity of this solution if there are a variable number inputs? If I consider the number of inputs to be constant, it brings my run time down to `O(m)` and space to `O(1)`, but OP doesn't specify its constant. The title says `multiples of 2 or more numbers` and the example provides 3.

Comment: Yeah, the question is ambiguous, but the OP mentioned counting twice and the example input doesn't include a terminator or a size, so it looks like there are always 3 numbers.

Comment: The number 6 wouldn't be considered missing if we interpret the question as finding the multiples constructed only from the input numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps mentioning N would have been helpful, regardless

let there be k numbers ; a[0],a[1],...,a[k-1]
and n is the maximum number of multiples upto the first number(L)

```
n = SUM(L/a[i]) ; i = 0, 1,..., k-1
```

Calculate and append the multiples to an array/container of size n
and a Hashmap of size L can be used to keep track of duplicates.

Space complexity will be **O(L)** and Time complexity **O(k*n)**